# TinyMCE public methods to parse HTML like paste plugin in other editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce, html-parsing, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

I have two editors in my application. One is tinyMCE and other is different one.
Is there any tinyMCE public methods that I can use to filter html tags and css that I can use for other editor.

```
pasteRetainStyleProperties = ['font-weight', 'font-style', 'font-size'];
pasteValidElements = ['b', 'strong', 'i', 'em'];
```

This is similar to the tinyMCE 4 feature. However I have to filter HTML string in the similar way. I am trying to build this for other editor. Hence I am wondering instead of building it from scratch is there any tinyMCE methods that I can use outside tinyMCE. Or any other 3rd party library help me achieve the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shridhar

Answer (score 1):

I believe, TinyMCE 5 has almost exactly the same options as that you've mentioned in the code block:

- [paste_retain_style_properties](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/paste/#paste_retain_style_properties)
- [paste_word_valid_elements](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/paste/#paste_word_valid_elements)

However, all the settings, defined in the `tinymce.init()` function cannot be changed without reinitialization. Reinitialization can be done very fast. You will need to perform 4 steps:

1. Save current content somewhere with [`getContent()`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#getcontent)
2. Destroy the TinyMCE instance with [`destroy()`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#destroy)
3. Reinitialize
4. Use [`setContent()`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#setcontent) to add the content saved on step 1.